# What is the difference between LSP and OCP?

Tags: solid-principles

I have been trying to break down the differences between the Open Closed Principal and Liskov's Substitution Principal.  And the best and most common examples of either use the exact same problem.  Finding the Area of a shape class.

They use slightly different means, but effectively solve the same problem with the same solution.

As these are both parts of SOLID, I'm really trying to find a reason to support why both are called out.

I'm looking for an explanation that doesn't work for both.

- Thanks.

Comment: preferably, a unique challenge/solution for OCP and LSP.

Answer (score 2):

LSP:

Consumers target an abstraction (e.g. interface) and should not need to know which concrete implementation stands behind the interface. For example, a client (e.g. a `DocumentProcessor` class) holds a dependency on `IDocumentStore`. If in V1, you gave it a `SqlSeverDocumentStore` instance, and then in V2 you gave it a `FileSystemDocumentStore`, the client (`DocumentProcessor`) should work without modification. This can be achieved by making sure the **contract** of `IDocumentStore` is well defined and that `DocumentProcessor`, `SqlSeverDocumentStore` and `FileSystemDocumentStore` abide by this contract.

The contract means much more than an interface. Having two classes implement the same interface does not mean they abide by the same contract (although they should).

For example, does both implementations support saving documents which are smaller or equal to 20MB? Or does one of them support documents that are at most 10MB? If it is part of the contract that an implementation should support 20MB documents, then all implementations should support this.

OCP:

We should avoid modifying a unit of composition (e.g. a class or a function) after we release it. One way to achieve this is to make the units parameterized. For example, if you have a function (say, `ProcessImages`) that reads images from the file system, compresses them and then sends them to some web service, you can parameterize this function to accept other functions that are responsible for (1) reading images, (2) compressing them, (3) sending them.

E.g. (in C#):

```
public static void ProcessImages(
    Func<Image[]> getImages,
    Func<Image, CompressedImage> compressImage,
    Action<CompressedImage> sendImage)
{
    //... Orchestrate the operation here
}
```

And, in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/):

```
Action processImages = () => ProcessImages(ReadImages, CompressImage, SendImage);
```

Where `ReadImages`, `CompressImage`, `SendImage` are themselves functions.

This way, if you want to change how the images are compressed, you will not modify the `ProcessImages` function. Instead you will create a new compression function (say `CompressImageInADifferentWay`) and then compose the `ProcessImages` function in the Composition Root like this:

```
Action processImages =
    () => ProcessImages(ReadImages, CompressImageInADifferentWay, SendImage);
```

If you apply the OCP in a perfect way, only the Composition Root itself will change.

LSP allows us to achieve OCP. For example, because `CompressImage` and `CompressImageInADifferentWay` abide by some contract that `ProcessImages` knows about, we can replace `CompressImage` with `CompressImageInADifferentWay` without modifying `ProcessImages`.